# Does Any() run the LINQ query

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

If I write a query for example:

```
var query = (from a in this.Context.Addresses where a.Active select a.Name);
```

then is it correct to say

```
if(query.Any())
 return query.ToList();

return null;
```

notice the query didn't have a `FirstOrDefault()` or `ToList()` so I am wndering if `.Any()` runs the query?

Comment: Yes, it does. If you don't find the word _deferred_ in the documentation you can be pretty sure that it executes the query and returns the result immediately.

Comment: If the query returns a result then it's safe to assume it has executed (how else would you receive a result).

Comment: So if I do the .ToList() on the original query and don't do the Any() check,  will it help performance too? because looks like this way we are running it two times? one with Any and one with ToList ?

Comment: @Bohn Yes, calling `Any` then calling `ToList` will run two _different_ SQL queries.  Calling `ToList` then `Any` will only execute one SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - it has to, given that it's got to return `true` or `false`. It can't *possibly* do that without running the query.

If you're going to conditionally return `ToList()`, you'd be better off writing:

```
var list = query.ToList();
return list.Any() ? list : null;
```

... or I'd actually recommend that you just return `query.ToList()` *anyway*, as it's a lot easier to write code which uses an empty list than to have to special-case a null value.

Comment: So if I do the .ToList() on the original query and don't do the Any() check, will it help performance too? because looks like this way we are running it two times? one with Any and one with ToList ? –

Comment: @Bohn: Well it depends if the result queries are cached, and exactly what the LINQ provider does with `Any` - but yes, I'd expect it to at least *potentially* help with performance.

Comment: @Bohn - yes - a query that ends with `Any` will be a different query than one that ends with `ToList`.  The `Any` will probably get translated to an `EXISTS` in SQL, while the `ToList` will execute the full query and return all of the records.  Calling `Any` on a list, however, is _very_ fast (probably much faster than the SQL call).  So calling `ToList` _then_ `Any` will likely be faster.  However, I agree with Jon that the standard practice is to return an empty collection rather than `null` (in which case you don't need the `Any` call).

Comment: I second the returning of an empty list instead of `null`.